# Missing permission в начале игры

Tags: android, unity3d

Убрал разрешение `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, при запуске игры пишет `missing permissions android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, не пойму где может запрашиваться, в настройках `unity Force internal`, манифест:
Используется: `Kdioz, Appodeal, DevtoDev`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    package="com.unity3d.player" 
    android:installLocation="internalOnly"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" 
    android:versionCode="1" 
    android:versionName="1.0" 
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  <supports-screens 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:xlargeScreens="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />


    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="org.onepf.openiab.permission.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />


    <!-- Sony -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonyericsson.home.permission.BROADCAST_BADGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.sonymobile.home.permission.PROVIDER_INSERT_BADGE"/>

    <permission
        android:name="com.oriplay.babyphone.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="com.oriplay.babyphone.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
    <!--PERMISSIONS END-->

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />

  <application 
    android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" 
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:debuggable="false"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:name="com.adservice.Application"
    >

        <!--##SERVICES START##-->
            <service
                android:name="com.adservice.AdService"
                android:enabled="true"
                android:exported="false"
                android:stopWithTask="false"
                />

            <service
                android:name="com.adservice.PushNotificationService"
                android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
                android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationExtender" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>

            <!--JobDispatcher-->

            <service
                android:name="com.adservice.after26.jobs.PingJob"
                android:exported="false"
                >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </service>

        <service android:name="com.adservice.after26.addons.AdServiceJob"
                 android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <service
            android:name="com.adservice.after26.addons.InternalLogJob"
            android:exported="false"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.ACTION_EXECUTE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <!--##SERVICES END##-->

    <!--##RECEIVERS START##-->
            <receiver android:name="com.adservice.receivers.BootUpReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                    <!--For HTC devices-->
                    <action android:name="com.htc.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <receiver android:name="com.adservice.receivers.ConnectivityReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <receiver android:name="com.adservice.receivers.UserPresentReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>

            <receiver android:name="com.adservice.receivers.AdServiceRestartReceiver" />

            <receiver android:name="com.adservice.receivers.EmergencyReceiver">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_STATE"/>
                    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED"/>
                    <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        <!--##RECEIVERS END##-->

    <!--#JOBDISPATCHER STARTS HERE#-->
            <service
                android:name="com.firebase.jobdispatcher.GooglePlayReceiver"
                android:exported="true"
                android:permission="com.google.android.gms.permission.BIND_NETWORK_TASK_SERVICE" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.ACTION_TASK_READY" />
                </intent-filter>
            </service>
    <!--#JOBDISPATCHER ENDS HERE#-->


    <!-- #ONESIGNAL STARTS HERE# -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="onesignal_app_id"
            android:value="a466b693-9132-43dd-b4ee-23c6e604ab27" />
        <!-- Deprecated - Pulled from OneSignal dashboard. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="onesignal_google_project_number"
            android:value="str:REMOTE" />
         <meta-data 
            android:name="com.onesignal.BadgeCount"
            android:value="DISABLE" />

        <receiver
            android:name="com.onesignal.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

                <category android:name="com.oriplay.babyphone" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationOpenedReceiver" />

        <service android:name="com.onesignal.GcmIntentService" />
        <service
            android:name="com.onesignal.GcmIntentJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name="com.onesignal.RestoreJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name="com.onesignal.RestoreKickoffJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />
        <service
            android:name="com.onesignal.SyncService"
            android:stopWithTask="true" />
        <service
            android:name="com.onesignal.SyncJobService"
            android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.onesignal.PermissionsActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar" />

        <service android:name="com.onesignal.NotificationRestoreService" />

        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.QUICKBOOT_POWERON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <receiver android:name="com.onesignal.UpgradeReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    <!-- #ONESIGNAL ENDS HERE# -->

    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">

      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.ForwardNativeEventsToDalvik" android:value="true" />
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
    </activity>

    <activity 
        android:name="org.onepf.openiab.UnityProxyActivity" 
        android:launchMode="singleTask" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:configChanges="fontScale|keyboard|keyboardHidden|locale|mnc|mcc|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|uiMode|touchscreen" />

    <receiver android:name="com.amazon.device.iap.ResponseReceiver">
      <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.NOTIFY" android:permission="com.amazon.inapp.purchasing.Permission.NOTIFY" />
      </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- Local Notifications -->
    <receiver android:name="com.androidnative.features.notifications.LocalNotificationReceiver"> </receiver>

    <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="true" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" /> 
   <!--- <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />-->
 <!---  <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />-->
    </application>


</manifest>
```

Comment: Без этого запроса не будет доступа к записи на флеш память, т.е. рекламу не загрузишь.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите манифесты плагинов, которые используете, так как при наличии нескольких манифестов в проекте, они могут мержиться автоматически. Особое внимание обратите на плагины рекламы, так как такие плагины чаще всего инициализируются и скачивают рекламные ролики для показа заранее в фоновом режиме, а не в момент востребования.
Касаемо тех, что вы перечислили:

- в appodeal [документации](https://www.appodeal.com/sdk/documentation?framework=1&full=1) описано, что они используют этот permission, но он опциональный и можно его убрать.
- в Kidoz [документации](https://github.com/Kidoz-SDK/KIDOZ_Android_SDK_Example-Android-Studio) также описано, что такой permission используется.